# Question on directional derivative for vector-valued functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, transpose, hessian-matrix

Let $\;f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m\;$. The gradient matrix of $\;f\;$ is :

$\;\nabla f=\begin{pmatrix}
            \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} \dots \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\
            \;\dots\;\\
          \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} \dots \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}\\  
         \end{pmatrix}\;$

And $\;v=(v^1,\dots,v^n)\;$ is the unit normal vector field.

I know $\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}= \nabla f \cdot v\;$.

**Question:**

If I take the transpose matrix $\;(\nabla f)^T\;$, then would it be true to claim $\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=(\nabla f)^T \cdot v\;$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first identity $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = v \cdot \nabla f$ doesn't make sense because $v$ is a $1 \times n$ vector while $\nabla f$ is a $m \times n$ matrix. Do you think of elements of $\mathbb{R}^n / \mathbb{R}^m$ as row vectors or column vectors? Is the gradient of a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a row vector or a column vector for you?

Comment: @levap Yes, you're right! My mistake... I'll edit my post. Hope it's better now

Comment: Again, this doesn't make sense. If you want the result $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ to be a row vector, the correct identity is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = (\nabla f \cdot v^T)^T = v \cdot (\nabla f)^T.$

Comment: @levap I'm sorry, multiplication of matrices with vectors is very confusing to me! I want $\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\;$ to be a column vector...

Comment: Then the correct equation is $\nabla f \cdot v^T$.

Comment: @levap Ok, but if I had the transpose of $\;\nabla f\;$, what would $\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\;$ be then?

Comment: You can also write it as $((\nabla f \cdot v^T)^T)^T = (v \cdot \nabla f^T)^T$.

Comment: @levap Ok... I guess i should see it more carefully. However thanks a lot for your time:)